# Scraping a Webpage with RSelenium

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape this link here: https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/hockey/88670853?category=player-props&subcategory=goalscorer -- and return the player props on the page in some sort of workable table within R where I can clean it to a final result.

I am working with the RSelenium package in combination with the tidyverse and rvest in order to scrape this info into R. I have had success on other pages on this website in the past, but can't seem to crack this one.

I've gotten as far as Inspecting the webpage down to the most granular `<div>` that contains the entire list of players on the page, and copied the corresponding xpath from that line of the inspection.

My code looks as such:

```
# Run this code to scrape the player props for goals from draftkings


library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)

# start up local selenium server 
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port=6511L, chromever = "96.0.4664.45")
remote_driver <- rD$client

# Open chrome
remote_driver$open()

# Navigate to URL
url <- "https://sportsbook.draftkings.com/leagues/hockey/88670853?category=player-props&subcategory=goalscorer"
remote_driver$navigate(url)


# Find the table via the XML path
table_xml <- remote_driver$findElement(using = "xpath", value = "//*[@id='root']/section/section[2]/section/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div") 

# Locates the table, turns it into a list, and binds into a single dataframe
player_prop_table <- table_xml$getElementAttribute("innerHTML")
```

That last line, instead of returning a workable list, tibble, or dataframe like I'm used to returns a large list that contains the same values I see on the Chrome inspect tool.

What am I missing here in terms of successfully scraping this page?

Comment: Selenium is not needed. You can query this API directly. https://sportsbook-us-ny.draftkings.com//sites/US-NY-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670853/categories/550?format=json. Use any JSON parser in R to read the content.

Comment: Hugely clutch. Thank you!

Comment: Hi again @ekoam -- I'm curious, how did you find the api link? Is it something you were previously familiar with, or is there a way to find this link via the link I provided? I'd like to try and repeat this process for other webpages if possible.

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, you need to [inspect network activities](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/). Also, you need to understand how basic web queries work and what are those files loaded when you do the inspection. Basically, just do tons of google searches until knowing things from the inside out. @gav

Comment: @ekoam can you give more detail how you are able to use R to download the JSON from the link https://sportsbook-us-ny.draftkings.com//sites/US-NY-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670853/categories/550?format=json? I have tried using the fromJSON function in jsonlite and simply download.file() in base R and I get a variety of could not open the connection errors. Only way I can get the JSON into R is by manually copy pasting it into notepad.

Comment: You might have been blocked. This works for me: `jsonlite::fromJSON("https://sportsbook-us-ny.draftkings.com//sites/US-NY-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670853/categories/550?format=json")` @Eric

Comment: When I try to run fromJSON with that link I get Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
  schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). The error is the same on both my comps. I just tried using a new IP address and the error is still there. This is so frustrating.